# Is there any set-theoretic axiom that is equivalent to "there exists a well-order on $\mathbb{R}$"?

Tags: set-theory, axiom-of-choice, well-orders

The question is as the title says: Is there any set-theoretic (ZF) axiom that is equivalent to "there exists a well-order on $\mathbb{R}$"? That is, I want a weaker axiom that axiom of choice that only imposes the statement. Axiom DC does not seem to be the one, so my question.

Comment: Presumably you are not looking for the 'axiom' "There exists a well-order on $\mathbb R$", so perhaps you could be more precise in what counts as an axiom for your purposes?

Comment: But as far as what I know, there is no explicit well-order on $\mathbb{R}$, right? We just assume that such a well-order exists via axiom of choice or weaker form of AC....

Comment: there is a formula of two free variables which, if $V = L$, the "axiom of constructibility", holds, defines a well-ordering of the reals. So you could use this formula, say $\phi(x,y)$, and then write a sentence claiming that $\phi(x,y)$ defines a well-ordering of the reals. This will be strictly weaker than $V = L$, and in particular weaker than the axiom of choice. Would that be what you're looking for?

Comment: @Mees de Vries: But this is not even a consequence of ZFC, so certainly it is not equivalent over ZF to "There is a well-ordering of the reals". Also, I don't see why being weaker than V=L means that you're weaker than the axiom of choice.

Comment: @MeesdeVries If you do this, the statement you get is equivalent to the statement that every real is constructible, which is much stronger than saying that there exists a well-ordering of the reals.  (For one thing, your statement implies the continuum hypothesis. But beyond that, it's *much* more restrictive in terms of which reals can exist.)

Comment: To clarify, I know that using the constructibility well-order is a "weird" answer to the original question -- the point is that the asker asked about an explicit well-order on $\mathbb R$, so I gave an example of an explicit relation that could be a well-order on $\mathbb R$, given the right axioms, to test if that would satisfy what they were looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing particular. Although this sort of question is often hard to answer to the negative, because you can never think about all the options.

As you noted, Dependent Choice is not enough; the same can be said on the Boolean Prime Ideal theorem.

Hardly anything which is not "more or less requiring this explicitly" gives you the wanted result. For example, "There is an infinite set whose power set can be well ordered", or "There exists $\alpha>\omega$ such that $V_\alpha$ can be well ordered" are more or less equivalent to "the reals can be well ordered". But maybe this is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an equivalent statement which might be of some interest to you:

*There is a choice function on the collection of all non-empty sets of reals.*

You can prove that this statement is equivalent to the statement that the reals can be well-ordered by following the usual proof that AC is equivalent to the statement that every set can be well-ordered:

1. If you have a well-ordering of the reals, you can define a choice function $f$ mapping $\;\mathscr{P}(\mathbb{R})\setminus\{\emptyset\}\;$ to $\mathbb{R}$ by simply letting $f(x)$ be the least element of $x$ according to the well-ordering.
2. Conversely, if you have such a choice function $f,$ you can get a well-ordering of $\mathbb{R}$ as follows. By Hartogs' theorem, there is a cardinal $\kappa$ so large that there is no 1-1 function from $\kappa$ to $\mathbb{R}.$  Using transfinite induction, define a function $g$ mapping some initial segment of $\kappa$ to $\mathbb{R}$ by setting $g(\alpha)=f(\mathbb{R}\setminus (g''\alpha))$ as long as $\mathbb{R}\setminus (g''\alpha)$ is non-empty. The domain of $g$ is some ordinal $\lambda\le\kappa.$  Also, $g$ is injective on its domain, so in fact we must have $\lambda\lt\kappa.$ Now $\lambda$ is not in the domain of $g,$ so $\mathbb{R}\setminus (g''\lambda)$ is empty.  It follows that $g$ is a bijection between $\lambda$ and $\mathbb{R},$ so the natural well-ordering of $\lambda$ induces a well-ordering of $\mathbb{R}.$

[In the argument above, $g''\alpha$ means the range of $g$ on $\alpha,$ or, equivalently, $\{g(\beta)\mid\beta\lt\alpha\}$.]